# Step in Kelley proof. closure of interior inequality

Tags: general-topology

In Kelley (p. 146) there is a theorem (rephrased)

> If X is a locally compact Hausdorff topological space, then the family of closed compact  neighborhoods of each point is a base for its neighborhood system.

In a step he defines $W:= \operatorname{int}(U\cap C)$ with $U$ open containing $x$ and $C$ a compact neighborhood of $x$. Then he says that $\operatorname{cl}(W)$ is compact Hausdorff.
Hausdorff property is hereditary and it is fine. To say that $\operatorname{cl}(W)$ is compact, he uses probably the fact that the $\operatorname{cl}(W)$ is closed and contained in the compact space $C$.

> How do I see that 
>   $$
> \operatorname{cl}(\operatorname{int}(U\cap C))\subseteq C
> $$
>   ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$U \cap C \subseteq C$ is clear, and taking the interior only makes it smaller, so

$$\operatorname{int}(U \cap C) \subseteq C$$ is also clear.

Now, $C$ is compact in a Hausdorff space, so closed, and hence (closures preserve inclusions, i.e. $A\subseteq B \implies \overline{A}\subseteq \overline{B}$):

$$\overline{\operatorname{int}(U \cap C)} \subseteq \overline{C}  =C$$

Note that $ U \cap C$ is a neighbourhood of $x$ as both $C$ and $U$ are, so $x$ lies in $\operatorname{int}(U \cap C)$, and is a subset of $U$.